# Xcode 6 'forget' Page Control position after Xcode restart

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode6, uipagecontrol

after `Xcode 6` installation **Xcode started to forget Page Control position** in View Controller. I have added also constraints and every time when I open `Xcode 6`, I see several issues:
 `Misplaced View - Frame for "Page Control" will be different at run time.` After frame update (`pushing yellow triangle`), everything is again correct until Xcode restarts. With **Xcode 5 everything worked fine**.

Any idea how to fix the issue?

I tried to add also screenshots, but as I'm new user, then it was impossible.

Thanks in advance,
Rainer

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried deleting the xcuserdata folder? I have seen things like this multiple times when updating Xcode, and most of the time it helps to delete the user's state data which is stored in xcuserdata:

Right-click the xcode project file:
[image]

and delete /xcuserdata

[image]

Comment: Eike, thank you for the reply. No, I have not tried to delete xcuserdata folder, but 'll keep it mind for future as I fixed the problem another way this time: I just deleted Page Controls, what I added with Xcode 5 and added new Page Controls with xCode 6 - it simply fixed the issue.